# VMWare security advisories in CVRF

Tags: vmware

I'm developping a crawler for security advisories and i wanted to crawl the VMWare website.

I know that there is a list of security advisories here : https://www.vmware.com/security/advisories/ but I wanted to know if they produce advisories in CVRF format (like Cisco or Oracle).

I have discovered that they are members of Icasi (the owner of CVRF) here: http://www.icasi.org/our-members/ but I can't seem to find any CVRF format advisory on the web.

Do you know if they produce such advisories, and if that's the case where they publish it ?